# If $ 0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n < 1$, will $a_{n}$ eventually become become always smaller than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is a sequence, $a_n>0$.

If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$, where $ 0 \leq L < 1$, then:

Is it possible to guarantee that there exists a $n_o$ sufficiently large for which $a_n < 1$ when $n>n_o$?

Moreover, is it possible to guarantee that there exists a $M$, $L<M<1$, such that $a_n<M$ for sufficiently large values of $n$?

I was trying to discuss those assertions using the definition of limit, i.e., for every real $\epsilon >0$, there exists a natural number $ n_{o}$ such that

$n> n_{o} \implies \left | a_{n} - L   \right | < \epsilon$

However, I couldn't conclude anything...

Is the definition of limit the best approach to discuss that?

Comment: Yes, it is a direct consequence of the limit. Take $\epsilon=M-L$. Whatever the $M$ you choose, there will be an $\epsilon$, and thus a $n_0$...

Comment: Try arguing by contraction. If $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$, then choose $\epsilon = \frac{1-L}{2}$ ... Similarly for your second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $L=\lim a_n$ and note that $1-L>0$. Then there exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies
$$
\lvert a_n-L\rvert < 1-L
$$
That is, $n>N$ implies
$$
L-1 < a_n-L <1-L
$$
Adding $L$ to this inequality gives $n>N$ implies
$$
a_n<1
$$
as desired.